# Spring IntegrationFlow is failing due to incorrect handle method

Tags: java, spring-integration, dsl

Hi I am trying to add Spring IntegrationFlow but dont know what is the error for following scenario.

My IntegrationConfig is as below

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class IntegrationConfig {
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sayHelloFlow(){
        String uri = "http://localhost:8081/hellos";
        return IntegrationFlows.from("integration.example.gateway.channel")
                .filter("headers['operation'] == 'OPERATION_A'")
                .<SearchRequest>handle((request) -> {
                    Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    header.put("a_header", request.getHeaders().get("initial_val", String.class));
                    SearchRequestB obj = new SearchRequestB(
                            request.getPayload()+"Modified",
                            header);
                })
                .handle(Http.outboundGateway(uri).httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST))
                .get();
    }
}
```

My IntegrationGateway class is

```
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.Gateway;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.MessagingGateway;

@MessagingGateway
public interface IntegrationGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "integration.example.gateway.channel")
    public String canSearch(String message);
}
```

In the above problem is once I remove **handle(Http.outboundGateway(uri).httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST))** line it works properly. and by keeping same line I am getting following error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow]: Factory method 'sayHelloFlow' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: The 'currentComponent' (com.integration.config.IntegrationConfig$$Lambda$793/0x0000000800567440@340cb97f) is a one-way 'MessageHandler' and it isn't appropriate to configure 'outputChannel'. This is the end of the integration flow.
```

I am wanted to call the another REST end point within this handle method.
What is wrong I am doing here
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem that `handle(Message<?>)` is really a one-way endpoint with a `void` return type and can be used only in the end of flow. That’s what that error about : since this endpoint cannot produce reply, there is no way to call the next endpoint in the flow. It is more suspicious that your code introduces that `obj` variable and does nothing with it.

See more in docs : https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-class-cast.

To fix your solution we need to know if you want to call a rest with that `obj` or in parallel  with this custom lambda.